# stomp client is not getting messages/notifications when SessionSubscribeEvent is happend

Tags: javascript, java, stomp, spring-websocket, sockjs

I've a subscribe listener as

```
@Service
public class UserSubscribeEventListenerService {

    private SimpMessagingTemplate template;
    @Autowired
    private GenericService<User> userService;

    @Autowired
    public UserSubscribeEventListenerService(SimpMessagingTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    @EventListener
    public void handleSubscribeEvent(SessionSubscribeEvent event) {
        try {
            String subscribedUser = event.getUser().getName();
            System.out.println("User is " + event.getUser().getName() + " Message is " + "GREETINGS" );
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            System.out.println("AFTER 3 seconds...." );
            template.convertAndSendToUser(subscribedUser, "/user/"+subscribedUser+ "/notify", userService.getByEmail(subscribedUser));
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getCause() 
                    + "\n\n"
                    + e.getCause());
            return;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getCause() 
                    + "\n\n"
                    + e.getCause());
            return;
        }
    }       
}
```

but client side which are bunch of JS functions for stomp given below

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
    //Create stomp client over sockJS protocol
    var socket = new SockJS("/ws");
    ///var socket = new SockJS("/ws");
    var stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
     $( document ).ready(function() {
         stompClient.connect({}, function(s) {    

                stompClient.subscribe('/user/' + s.headers['user-name'] + '/notify', function(frame){
                    var messages = JSON.parse(frame.body)

                      var i;
                      var count = 0;
                      for( i in messages) {
                          var message = messages[i]; 
                          count ++;
                          if(count <= 5){
                              $('#user_message_addon').append(
                                $('<li>').append(                                       
                                      $('<span></span>').html(message.notificationMessage)
                                    ),
                                    $('</li>')      
                                )
                              );
                          }
                        }                            
                });             

            });
        });
    </script>
```

is not seems to work properly, not showing or say not getting messages sent by by server when ever `UserSubscribeEventListenerService` event is occurred I'm getting console output at client side as

[image: Image showing console output]

but I'm unable to get message/notifications.

Can any body tell me how to resolve that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try changing `convertAndSendToUser` arguments to:

```
template.convertAndSendToUser(subscribedUser, "/notify", userService.getByEmail(subscribedUser));
```

or

```
template.convertAndSendToUser(subscribedUser, "/user/notify", userService.getByEmail(subscribedUser));
```

I think spring changes queue name itself depending on user name. 
Or you can do it with `convertAndSend` method:

```
template.convertAndSend("/"+subscribedUser+"/notify", userService.getByEmail(subscribedUser));
```

or

```
template.convertAndSend("/user/"+subscribedUser+"/notify", userService.getByEmail(subscribedUser));
```

It depends on your websocket configuration (could you include it in your question?)

Comment: First suggestion worked well, others may work but did not tried, thanks again.

Comment: I wanna ask a question, I think you wouldn't mind that, question is _how can I get user from list of users and send message to him `stompClient.send("here-how-to-set-destination", {}, "Hi to selected user");`_? Can you answer (refer  a source on the net) please.

Comment: Hard to answer when I don't know your usecase. One idea would be to pass userName (List of users) via your Model to view and use it in your js code. But more details would be useful.